# Instance name/default instance

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have SQL Server Express running on machine GERSWHIN. On GERSHWIN itself, SSMS connects using: GERSWHIN\SQLEXPRESS.

The server is running on port 1344, and from the Internet, I can telnet into GERSHWIN, exposed as, say, abc.com, on port 1344.

From another computer using SSMS, what should be the string to use in the `Server name` field to connect to this SQL Server?

I tried `abc.com:1344` and `abc.com:1344\SQLEXPRESS` but both got the same error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use either machinename\instancename or machinename:port - not both. The browser translates instance name to port. The default port is 1433 - are you **sure** that your instance is configured with 1344? Hope you know the risk of exposing your machine/instance to the internet. Default install of express does not [enable tcp interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: MS official connection [trouble shooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/sbs/topic/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server-ae23c94b-b64b-5056-8b62-22e1694bb889?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: In order to use instance names remotely, e.g.: `hostname\sqlexpress`, you need to have the SQL Browser service running on the target machine, and the target machine's firewall needs to allow incoming traffic on udp/1434. As to what to put in the SSMS connection dialog's Server field, it depends on your default client driver. It will either be `hostname:1344` (colon) or `hostname,1344` (comma).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Your comment is spot on. Need connectivity on UDP/1434 and just use `hostname\sqlexress`, or `hostname,SQL Service port`.